# Canvas fill style is randomly changing

Tags: javascript, html

i have a checkerboard. When the user hovers their mouse over a tile, it will highlight in yellow. When this happens, the game border will also turn yellow aswell as the last white checkers border.

I didnt even set the checkers to have a border so I have no idea why this is happening.

I draw the border like this:

```
context.fillStyle = '#000';
context.lineWidth = Math.min(canvas.width, canvas.height) / 170;

context.rect(board.gapW ,board.gapW, board.w - (board.gapW * 2), board.h - (board.gapH * 2));
context.stroke();
```

As you can see I set it to black everytime

I draw the checkers like this:

```
context.fillStyle = (board.info[i][j].c == 1) ? checkers.colours[checkers.colour].p1 : checkers.colours[checkers.colour].p2;
context.beginPath();
context.arc(x + (board.squareW / 2), y + (board.squareH / 2), r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);                    
context.fill();
```

The fill style is either black or white in this case and no border line is even used.

Here is a live version to see: http://jsfiddle.net/xupkmc60/2/

Border is line 78-82
Checker is line 111-114

Comment: you should use context.save/restore methods when drawing stuffs and changing fill/stroke styles.

Comment: ive never heard of that, i will look into this, thanks

Comment: `strokeStyle` can be used for the border color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the user hovers their mouse over a tile

You set the `strokeStyle` to yellow in your `event` listener. This never gets reset to default value when you draw the board again.

To fix this you could either put `context.strokeStyle = 'black'` at the beginning of your `drawBoard` method, or use `save` and `restore` to preserve the state when drawing the board *again*.

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the border problem. Do you know why its drawing a border on the last checker though?

Comment: @RachelDockter, yes - that's because you initialized  a `beginPath` when the last checker was drawn and when you call `stroke` in the `highlightTile` method the last checker will include. To solve this put `context.beginPath()` after `drawBoard()` in your `highlightTile` method.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different types of context styles here: `fillStyle` and `strokeStyle`. You set the `strokeStyle` to `yellow` in `highlightTile`, but never unset it. I believe if you reset the `strokeStyle` as part of `drawBoard` you should be good.

That said, you may wish to use [save](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save) and [restore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore) methods in functions that modify the canvas context to avoid this sort of inadvertent state leaking.

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the border but i still dont know why its creating a border for the checker. I will use save and restore methods so I wont face any problems like this again